# Celery - TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, celery

So I tried looking for some answer eg([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58023234/typeerror-object-of-type-bytes-is-not-json-serializable-python3),[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58452367/object-of-type-bytes-is-not-json-serializable-in-python3) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58023234/typeerror-object-of-type-bytes-is-not-json-serializable-python3)) but the solutions don't make any sense. I am sending bytes to Celery. and for some reason it tells me that it's JSON-serializable while I am not even using JSON

```
write_file_aws.delay(file_full_name, file_to_put) #file_fill_name - str type, file_to_put - bytes type
```

and there I have the error I tried also decoding it but I had this problem

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 113: invalid continuation byte
```

so I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699367/for-line-in-results-in-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte) and just another error. Why can't I send a byte-type variable to celery? Is that something impossible to send to a celery function?

backend framework- Flask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that you just can't pass a byte type variable to a Celery function. If you have to you can turn it to a list save it in a database then call it inside the function. Or encode it to base64 and then in thr function decode it.